# Support for gravity in the viewer

Tags: autodesk-viewer

In the Forge API Webinar on Feb 14 it was said that the viewer now supports gravity in walk mode, e.g walking up a stair. To which version of the viewer does this apply, and how is it supposed to work? Does it have to be enabled etc?

Answer (score 0):

Gravity and walkthroughs aren't enabled yet. It's still work in progress.